# How to add a line number follow by a tab to a text file

Tags: text-processing, nl

I tried using

```
nl -ba -s '\t' full_media > full_media2
```

But it really did not add the tab, but it added actually the "\t" text after the line number. The file im editing is a CSV file and here by i'm trying to add a new column to the beginning with id.

Comment: Doesn't `cat -n` work? The command you propose but without `-s '\t'` seems to work too. What am I missing?

Comment: if i so not add -s part, it will just add the number to the 1st, but it will not add the tab separator with original column. Here I'm trying to add a new id column to my CSV file

Comment: For me, both `cat -n` and `nl -ba` print the line number then a tab, then the original line contents. Maybe we are using different versions of the tools.

Comment: Real CSV files (not an artificial subset) can have newlines within a (quoted) cell value. Using your approach is going to mangle these CSV files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a modern shell like bash or zsh, use `$` so that the shell evaluates `\t` and replaces it with an actual tab:

```
nl -ba -s $'\t' full_media > full_media2
```

Even so, if you examine the output, it looks like the default separator is a tab:

```
$ nl -ba -s $'\t' ~/at.sh | od -c
0000000                       1  \t   n   o   h   u   p       s   g    
$ nl -ba  ~/at.sh | od -c        
0000000                       1  \t   n   o   h   u   p       s   g
```

Indeed, the default separator is tab, as specified by POSIX. From [`man nl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nl.1posix):

```
   -s  sep
          Specify  the  characters  used in separating the line number and
          the corresponding text line. The default sep shall be a <tab>.
```

---

To add a column to the CSV, try using Python:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python2

from sys import stdin, stdout
import csv

csvin = csv.reader(stdin, delimiter='\t')
csvout= csv.writer(stdout, delimiter='\t')
count = 1

for row in csvin:
    csvout.writerow ([count] + row)
    count = count + 1
```

Save it as a script (say `nl.py`) and run:

```
python2 nl.py < full_media > full_media2
```

Comment: Is `$'\t'` available in standard Bourne shell? I think it might not be.

Comment: @Celada No, it isn't. I'll update.